# Comments no longer shown in All Actions

Tags: support, comment, recent-activity

Up to quite recently (today perhaps!), when I clicked on my profile and then on "All actions" and "Comments", I used to see both the title of the question and the contents of the comments. Now I only see the title of the question.

How can I see the contents of the comments as well?

Here is URL that gets me there:
https://math.stackexchange.com/users/589/lhf?tab=activity&sort=comments

Comment: The bug report on [meta.se] (posted just a few minutes ago): [Comment excerpts missing on "All actions" section of user "Activity" tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376539).

Comment: And MathJax is broken again in some places.

Comment: It seems to be fixed now.

Comment: @RandomVariable perhaps you could make a different post highlighting where the MathJax appears broken?